# NpgSql.dll with Ninjatrader 8 - Could not load Assembly

Tags: .net, npgsql, trading

This issue falls outside Ninjatrader support.
The latest version of Ninjatrader (NT8) uses .net framework 4.8. The npqsql libraries provided by nuget are netstandard 2.0, 2.1, netcoreapp3.1 and net5.0,6.0,7.0. Given this list only the netstandard2.1 qualifies.

An old NT8 forum post suggested using netstandard.dll  to the NT8 config.xml. After identifying and adding the following references using the NT8 editor add reference feature the config file has:

```
      <string>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll</string>
      <string>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Drawing.dll</string>
      <string>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.Common.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\netstandard.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Buffers.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Memory.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Text.Json.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Threading.Channels.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</string>
      <string>*MyDocuments*\NinjaTrader 8\bin\Custom\System.ValueTuple.dll</string>
      <string>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ComponentModel.dll</string>
```

A simple test strategy adapted from the sample moving average crossover strategy has:

```
     else if (State == State.Configure)
    {
        try
                {
                    Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection xconn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(ConnStr);
                    xconn.Open();
            Print(Name+" Npgsql opened conn string:"+ConnStr);
                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
        {
                 Print(Name+" DBconnect error:"+ex.Message.ToString()); 
                }
    }
```

Invoking the code via Strategy Analyzer and inspecting both log and trace files confirms that all dependencies for npgsql were loaded without errors:

```
23-04-19 20:34:26:987|1|4|Vendor assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces' version='7.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:987|1|4|Vendor assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode' version='1.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:988|1|4|Vendor assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' version='6.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:988|1|4|Vendor assembly 'netstandard' version='2.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:989|1|4|Vendor assembly 'Npgsql' version='7.0.2.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:990|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Buffers' version='4.0.3.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:990|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable' version='7.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:991|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' version='6.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:991|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Memory' version='4.0.1.2' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:991|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors' version='4.1.4.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:992|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' version='6.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:992|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web' version='7.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:993|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Text.Json' version='7.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:993|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Threading.Channels' version='7.0.0.0' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:994|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions' version='4.2.0.1' loaded.
2023-04-19 20:34:26:994|1|4|Vendor assembly 'System.ValueTuple' version='4.0.0.0' loaded.
```

Despite this the call to xconn.open() throws the following exception:

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

On another machine the error was the same but a different dll like System.Memory was shown.

Also in Visual Studio 2022 running a simple project with .net framework 4.8 runs npqsql successfully on a variety of database functions. Only the confirmed set of dlls used in the VS project were used in NT8 to minimize versioning conflicts.

Has anyone ever succeeded in using NpqSql within Ninjatrader ?